# SQL Multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, select

My Table data looks like

```
 Col1  | Col2 | Col3
    1  | NULL | NULL
  NULL |  2   | NULL
  NULL | NULL |  3
```

It is given that for any column there will be only entry. This means that, in the above data, if row1 has value for Col1, then there will be no row with value for Col1. Similarly, if row1 has value for Col1, it will not have value for any other column.

I want to write a query, so that I get only one row out for entire data (leaving NULL values). ie.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
  1  |  2   |  3
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns?

Comment: @IanNelson: I am on Oracle. I want a query, which is independent of DB. Does DB really matter?

Comment: @IanNelson: The DataTypes are fixed. Some are int, Some are varchar etc.

Comment: Are you sure your table will have only 3 rows? If yes then its pretty straightforward. Else you will need some more criteria/information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using aggregation:

```
select max(col1) as col1, max(col2) as col2, max(col3) as col3
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
sum(ifnull(col1,0)) as col1, 
sum(ifnull(col2,0)) as col2
sum(ifnull(col3,0)) as col3
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is called tab the following query will work if there are only 3 columns:

```
select t1.Col1, t2.Col2, t3.Col3
from tab t1, tab t2, tab t3
where t1.Col1 is not null and t2.Col2 is not null and t3.Col3 is not null
```

The problem is the query will have to alias the table for each additional column. It may not be perfect, but it is a solution.